# Numpy: Add rows from one matrix to another by index

Tags: python, numpy

In short I want to index into a matrix and add to each row.

In this example the first row (indexed by the 0) should get `[1,1,1]` added to it. Then the second row (indexed by the 1) should get `[2, 2, 2]` added to it. Finally the first row (indexed by the third 0) should get `[3, 3, 3]` added to it.

```
>>> a = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a[np.array([0,1,0]), :] += np.array([np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([2,2,2]), np.array([3,3,3])])
```

Desired:

```
>>> a
array([[5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Actual:

```
>>> a
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Edit 2:

As per comments below the solution runs slowly. From a portion of the code where I'm just adding 0 to test the speed:

```
print y.shape
print dW.shape
np.add.at(dW, (y, slice(None)), 0)
```

Yields:

```
(49000,)
(10, 3073)
```

And takes about 21 seconds. Without the `np.add.at` line the rest of the code takes about 1 second.
[y.npy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvwcudxmgevbsq6/y.npy?dl=0)
[dW.npy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmm729ntoeyog4h/dW.npy?dl=0)

Comment: could you *verbally* explain what your addition should mean? In fact, you're trying to replace row 0 twice in your assignment, so I think it's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Done! let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: Document this well in your code.  Otherwise it's a lurking bug/feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem of `numpy`, explained well [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

> For example, a[[0,0]] += 1 will only increment the first element once
>   because of buffering, whereas add.at(a, [0,0], 1) will increment the
>   first element twice.

`numpy` solves the problem using `add.at()`. Example:

```
a = array([1,2,3])
add.at(a,[0,0],4) # now a = array([9, 2, 3])
```

In this case we want this to work for a multidimensional array:

```
a = np.array([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])])
np.add.at(a,([0,1,0],slice(None)),array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]))
```

The result is:

```
array([[5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]])
```

I guess you mistyped a `7` for a `6`.

Comment: Thanks! You got me unstuck!

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in a vectorized way?

Comment: this is the vectorized way

Comment: Hmm, I'm using this in an implementation and it's 5x slower than just using loops. It might be the slice(None) -- I'm still getting familiar with numpy, is that necessary?

Comment: This is interesting. Yes it could be because the operation is on a 2D array. And yes I think you really need the slice. Please post an example so that we can work on it.

Comment: I added the code and attached the y.npy and dW.npy files to reproduce with. Thanks for all the help!